# null check in while loop in Scala, unusual behaviour

Tags: scala, while-loop

I am aggregating the contents of an `InputStream` using a `BufferedReader` using the form

```
while( (str = br.readLine()) != null){
  sb.append(str)
}
```

but this quickly caused an `OutOfMemoryError` as the null check failed to pick up the null and my `StringBuffer` keeps increasing in size...

I have verified that `str` does have a value of `null` and also verified that it is not `"null"`.

Refactoring my code to

```
str = br.readLine()
while(str != null){
  sb.append(str)
  str = br.readLine()
}
```

works but I've no idea how this would be any different. Any ideas?

Comment: There are more Scala-like ways to read in the content of a file, for example: `val sb = new StringBuilder; Source.fromFile(myFile).addString(sb)`

Comment: @Jesper the problem here is that I am using a Java library :) I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala the expression `str = br.readline()` yield return value of type `Unit`, which is always not equal to null. It should have given you a warning about comparing `Unit` to null.

You are correct to refactor it like that.

P.S. As @Jesper correctly commented your question, this is not the way you usually read a file in scala. So if you do that - please use his code example. If you have any other `InputStream`, you can use `Source.fromInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

Archeg has explained it beautifully so try this :

```
var str = ""
while({str = br.readLine; str != null}) {

}
```

and since you are working in Scala, try using

```
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).getLines().mkString("\n")
```

or

```
 val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
 Iterator continually bufferedReader.readLine takeWhile (_ != null) mkString
```